# AutoHotkey script for toggling Sublime Text 3 sidebar or is there a native ST setting?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, autohotkey

I'm trying to write an AutoHotkey script for toggling Sublime Text 3's sidebar. Here's what I have so far:

```
; Custom Script for Sublime Text 3
; Map 'F10' key to Control+k, Control+b (open/close sidebar)

; If in Sublime Text
#IfWinActive ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS
F10::
    Send {Ctrl down}
    SetKeyDelay -1
    Send {k down}
    SetKeyDelay 0
    Send {Ctrl down}
    SetKeyDelay -1
    Send {b down}
return
```

So far I can toggle the sidebar closed but the script is not toggling it back open.

The script actually causes weird keyboard functionality in Windows so I don't recommend testing it as is.

How can I rewrite this so it toggles the sidebar properly?

Comment: Why don't you just change the keybind in Sublime itself? `{ "keys": ["f10"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" }`, that should do it.

Comment: ...because I did not know of this setting :/

Comment: That is brilliant!! In fact, turns out the hotkeys are actually Ctrl + k +b.....and not Ctrl+k and Ctrl+b. Regardless, I'd rather go with the native settings. Thank you @Sidola!

Comment: I amended the title, if you move your comment to an answer box then I can mark it.

Comment: One of the strengths of sublime is customization whether it be syntax, build tools, or shortcuts. I see very little need to use AHK for anything within it.

Comment: True but some settings don't seem so obvious. I've gone through the ST API docs but apparently I overlooked the toggle_side_bar setting. That said, I don't like using long hotkeys. For example, the command palette. I don't like clicking Ctrl+Shift+p...I used AHK to map it to just F9. This toggles the command palette easily. That's a personal choice that makes my workflow feel a bit more productive for me.

Comment: `{ "keys": ["f9"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette"} }` :). It's easy to find existing commands if you take a look at `Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default`, then just copy what you want to change over to your `Key Bindings - User`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change that within Sublime.

Go to `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings - User` and paste this:

```
[
    { "keys": ["f10"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" }
]
```

If you already have a bunch of custom key bindings, omit the square brackets.

```
{ "keys": ["f10"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" }
```